# How can I use Spring TaskExecutor to execute a workflow?

Tags: java, spring

How can I use Spring TaskExecutor to execute a workflow , I have a set of modules that needs to be executed followig an exact workflow with conditions for each module . The modules has to be external produced to the system as jar a jar file . The execution of a module is set by a specific timing and number of execution .

Any one have any proposition or an exemple of using Spring TaskExecutor .

Thanks

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html I guess you should google first!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```
class Quartz1 {
    @Scheduled(cron="* * * * * ?")
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("!!!!");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Quartz {

    @Bean
    public Quartz1 quartz1() {
        return new Quartz1();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Quartz.class);
    }
}
```

scheduling imlementation is in spring-context-xxx.jar. More info here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html